# Define optional query parameters in serverless.yml

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am fairly new to serverless framework (sls) and trying to define a function and deploy it to AWS.

While declaring a function in `serverless.yml`, I have defined the necessary parameters for a function along the lines of the following snippet but I am not able to define an **optional query parameter** in the http path of the new function:

```
function-name:
    handler: path/to/js/file.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/v1/resource/{limit}
          method: GET
```

**Desired behavior:** The issue is that I am not able to declare an optional parameter in the path. I wish the endpoint would work as expected even if the `limit` parameter in not passed in the http GET request.

*Note:* I have tried `path: api/v1/resource/{limit?}` but no luck.

Comment: You can get the query parameters in the event parameter of your handler function as event.queryStringParameters. You don't have to declare them in the serverless.yml as path parameters.

Comment: I just want to add that, you can read event.queryStringParameters (object) containing your params, but if no param is provided then event.queryStringParameters (null), so make sure to check type first before destructuring or reading properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another path for your Lambda to respond to.

```
function-name:
    handler: path/to/js/file.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/v1/resource/{limit}
          method: GET
      - http:
          path: api/v1/resource/
          method: GET
```

Then, handle it properly inside your Lambda function.